# Summing up attributes overlapping polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, overlapping-features, count

I have large single layers with many features overlapping, like this:
[image]

Where the features overlap I want the attributes added together.
I've managed to count the number of overlap polygons by doing union then aggregate, I'll have this result: [image]

but I'd also like to manage to have an output with the "sum" of the zone descriptions for each polygon overlap.

Comment: You can also look at the Overlap analysis tool in the Vector Analysis group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `overlay_intersects` on the aggregated layer

```
array_to_string(overlay_intersects( 'conflits',"zone_description"))
```

[image]